# Fortran 90 : return error

Tags: fortran, return, fortran90, subroutine

Hello I am a new user in fortran.

I try to use a subroutine for my project. The code is quite simple and below is the code

```
subroutine initial_data(f, x, y, z)
implicit none
   REAL                 :: f, x, y, z

  ! Adding function
   #include "func_expr.h"

  return
end subroutine
```

func_expr.h is separate file that I created because expression of f is really complicated. And I got the following error messages:

> error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'RETURN' when expecting one of: * ) :: ,  ; . (/ + - : ] /) ' ** / // > .LT. < ...
>       return
>   ----^

and

> error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [RETURN]
>       return
>   ----^
>
> compilation aborted for initial.f90.f (code 1)

I am not sure which part is wrong and why return has the problem of it.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. The question cannot be answered without your code. Please be sure to read [mcve]. The included file is important. You can delete the irrelevant parts of the large fie, but the error must be reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I found the error by myself. Next time, I will put more details

Comment: In that case either delete your post or edit and answer it.